# Powershell string to var

Tags: powershell

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and searched for hours but can't find it how to solve it

Problem:
All I want is basically to get a string, and then use it as a variable name.

Example:

```
Eval('SomeText') = 'someinfo'
```

Which would out come like:

```
$SomeText (which contains 'someinfo')
```

Maybe a little bit hard to explain hope you guys understand it, it's probably something simple but I just don't know how to do this in PowerShell scripting.

Comment: $SomeText = 'someinfo' isn't working? I think I am misunderstanding this. Oh! Do you mean setting the name of the variable based on results of another operation?

Comment: yes exactly setting the name of the variable based on the result of another operation (sorry for the language barrier)

Comment: All good - so, you can use Set-Variable to do this. Example: Set-Variable -Name (Eval('SomeText')) -Value 'someinfo'

Comment: Thanks Jeeva Set-Variable -Name ´SomeText' -Value ´someinfo' is working flawless! appreciate your help!

Comment: Not a problem! Have a good day.

Comment: @Apollyon rather than editing the title to include `[Solved]`, please accept an answer if you found it has been helpful.

Comment: @arco444 didn't knew how it worked before, figured it out thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Set-Variable to set a variable variable name, as shown below.

```
PS> Set-Variable -Name ($env:COMPUTERNAME) -Value "sometext"
PS> Get-Variable -Name ($env:COMPUTERNAME)

Name                           Value
----                           -----
jr-pc                          sometext
```

You can also refer to the variable with (in this case):

```
$($env:COMPUTERNAME)
```